# How to create a column using conditional arguments from three other columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe as shown below.

For every `as_of` value, I need to create a new column called `3months`, that adds the values from the `value` column for the 3 next `date` values available.

For example, for 2017-02-24 I need a new column that adds the value of 2017-06-01 + 2017-07-01 + 2017-08-01 (so 564 + 1232 + 1955).

```
                  value       as_of        date
id_region                                      
Total_Raws   564.664000  2017-02-24  2017-06-01
Total_Raws  1232.714000  2017-02-24  2017-07-01
Total_Raws  1955.152000  2017-02-24  2017-08-01
Total_Raws  2303.869000  2017-02-24  2017-09-01
Total_Raws  2709.538500  2017-02-24  2017-10-01
Total_Raws  2860.520500  2017-02-24  2017-11-01
Total_Raws  3239.112500  2017-02-24  2017-12-01
Total_Raws  3388.054500  2017-02-24  2018-01-01
Total_Raws  3464.291500  2017-02-24  2018-02-01
Total_Raws  3495.216500  2017-02-24  2018-03-01
Total_Raws  3502.185499  2017-02-24  2018-04-01
Total_Raws  3946.390499  2017-02-24  2018-05-01
Total_Raws  4907.220499  2017-02-24  2018-06-01
Total_Raws  5945.310498  2017-02-24  2018-07-01
Total_Raws  6846.689498  2017-02-24  2018-08-01
Total_Raws  7415.436498  2017-02-24  2018-09-01
Total_Raws     0.000000  2017-03-03  2016-10-01
Total_Raws     0.000000  2017-03-03  2016-11-01
Total_Raws    -0.400000  2017-03-03  2016-12-01
Total_Raws     0.700000  2017-03-03  2017-01-01
Total_Raws   -60.150000  2017-03-03  2017-02-01
Total_Raws  -239.991000  2017-03-03  2017-03-01
Total_Raws  -350.018000  2017-03-03  2017-04-01
Total_Raws  -456.551000  2017-03-03  2017-05-01
Total_Raws   217.054000  2017-03-03  2017-06-01
Total_Raws   797.104000  2017-03-03  2017-07-01
Total_Raws  1465.542000  2017-03-03  2017-08-01
Total_Raws  1845.259000  2017-03-03  2017-09-01
Total_Raws  2257.929000  2017-03-03  2017-10-01
Total_Raws  2391.411000  2017-03-03  2017-11-01
Total_Raws  2948.003000  2017-03-03  2017-12-01
Total_Raws  2911.445000  2017-03-03  2018-01-01
Total_Raws  2746.672000  2017-03-03  2018-02-01
Total_Raws  2930.597000  2017-03-03  2018-03-01
Total_Raws  3152.576999  2017-03-03  2018-04-01
Total_Raws  3775.781999  2017-03-03  2018-05-01
Total_Raws  4801.611999  2017-03-03  2018-06-01
Total_Raws  5814.701998  2017-03-03  2018-07-01
Total_Raws  6666.080998  2017-03-03  2018-08-01
Total_Raws  7329.827998  2017-03-03  2018-09-01
```

Comment: Can you provide the full expected output?  what should happen for the other rows?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use a rolling sum for this.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""value as_of date
564.664000 2017-02-24 2017-06-01
1232.714000 2017-02-24 2017-07-01
1955.152000 2017-02-24 2017-08-01
2303.869000 2017-02-24 2017-09-01
2709.538500 2017-02-24 2017-10-01
2860.520500 2017-02-24 2017-11-01
3239.112500 2017-02-24 2017-12-01
3388.054500 2017-02-24 2018-01-01
3464.291500 2017-02-24 2018-02-01
3495.216500 2017-02-24 2018-03-01
3502.185499 2017-02-24 2018-04-01
3946.390499 2017-02-24 2018-05-01
4907.220499 2017-02-24 2018-06-01
5945.310498 2017-02-24 2018-07-01
6846.689498 2017-02-24 2018-08-01
7415.436498 2017-02-24 2018-09-01
"""), sep=" ")

# just ensure that the dates are in the correct order
df = df.sort_values(by=['as_of', 'date'], ascending=False)

# get the rolling sum
df['3months'] = df.rolling(3).sum()
print(df)
```

This will give you NaN for the final two values (because there's not enough lookahead data to sum up for the final two time periods) and then gives you the answer you're looking for:

```
          value       as_of        date       3months
15  7415.436498  2017-02-24  2018-09-01           NaN
14  6846.689498  2017-02-24  2018-08-01           NaN
13  5945.310498  2017-02-24  2018-07-01  20207.436494
12  4907.220499  2017-02-24  2018-06-01  17699.220495
11  3946.390499  2017-02-24  2018-05-01  14798.921496
10  3502.185499  2017-02-24  2018-04-01  12355.796497
9   3495.216500  2017-02-24  2018-03-01  10943.792498
8   3464.291500  2017-02-24  2018-02-01  10461.693499
7   3388.054500  2017-02-24  2018-01-01  10347.562500
6   3239.112500  2017-02-24  2017-12-01  10091.458500
5   2860.520500  2017-02-24  2017-11-01   9487.687500
4   2709.538500  2017-02-24  2017-10-01   8809.171500
3   2303.869000  2017-02-24  2017-09-01   7873.928000
2   1955.152000  2017-02-24  2017-08-01   6968.559500
1   1232.714000  2017-02-24  2017-07-01   5491.735000
0    564.664000  2017-02-24  2017-06-01   3752.530000
```